# Can't install Apache 2.4 on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I've tried multiple PPAs, none have worked, I checked the policy on the Caché, tried to clear it, it returns the same. It insists on trying to install Apache 2.2 when I need 2.4.

Here's the result of     sudo apt-cache policy apache2

```
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
  Version table:
     2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.22-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this [Link](https://www.server.lu/faq/question/how-to-set-up-apache-2-4-php-5-5-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-10)

for installing apache 2.4 on your ubuntu machine.

may help you.

Comment: The problem is I keep getting 2.2 installed. I've tried adding PPAs, nothing works.

Comment: first install apache 2.2 and then update to 2.4 here is [link](https://blog.cloudtroopers.com/how-update-apache-http-server-22-24-ubuntu-server).

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes on the distribution the packages were being gotten for inside Software Center -> Edit -> Software sources -> other sources.

Changed the distribution to Utopic, then performed a banish404 using the packages in [this ppa](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwippO3s6srJAhUqpIMKHeErB64QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2F~fossfreedom%2F%2Barchive%2Fubuntu%2Fpackagefixes&usg=AFQjCNGsEGAkYUU1c7xRAStoeLloMPJ_cA&sig2=nECgywWqkg9jlPW21xvgxQ), and things work now.

Thank you all for your answers.